# downloaded software in Conda environment does not show in ls command

Tags: conda

I installed gzip package in Conda environment, then  to make sure the software was there, I used "ls" command, it was not in the list. Tried to install again, system says all the packages have already installed, Why? How do I check the list of software installed in the environment? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just type

```
conda list gzip
```

OR

```
conda list | grep gzip
```

OR if its installed in a given environment

```
conda activate myenv
```

or else just `activate myenv` system depending followed by either of the first two commands.

It is better to use `conda-navigate` a very nice and under used GUI, and would work in this particular instance. The details are found in an earlier post I made on esentially the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701571/what-is-the-right-way-to-update-anaconda-and-conda-base-environments/57936966#57936966) together with a pretty picture.

`ls` will only work if you type `ls ~/Anaconda3/bin | grep gzip` , but depends on the installation, e.g. you might have installed miniconda.

Having said all that `conda` is very cool, but whatever you do NEVER use `pip` or `pip3` from this moment onwards EVER, it messes up your conda and you'll need to `env` your way out of it.